Wireguard VPN to device in network (via internet) does not work?
I am an absolute Wireguard-Greenhorn, sorry for that!
We have this setup
Some local network with at least 1 device (Raspberry Pi based data logger) and 1 router for internet access (connected via ethernet).
Some PC wants to connect to the data logger, at least for installation / configuration, via internet, but in a secure way. No other party should be able to do this.
So we've thought, we would need a VPN and installed two Wireguard VPNs on the router. One for the data logger, one for the outside world. Both clients (data logger, PC) use the Wireguard configuration for starting their own Wireguard.

Problem
The Wireguard VPNs seem to work, no error messages. And I can tunnel all my internet traffic from the PC through the router. But when I try to hit the IP (192.168.?.?) of the data logger in the local network of the router, I am running into a timeout.
Questions

Do we really need two Wireguard VPNs? Why not a single one?
Using the Wireguard config files of the router at the clients for their Wireguard config seems to be very wrong to me. Using the same address for the interface (for server and client, the two Wireguard VPNs of the router do have different addresses) is actually not supposed to work? But it does work, why? Also, they have (beside the keys) just one difference: the address of the [Inteface]: Address = 192.168.115.202/24 / Address = 192.168.115.201/24.

Both Wireguard configs have:
[Peer]
PublicKey = ...key...
PresharedKey = ...another key...
AllowedIPs = 192.168.115.0/24,0.0.0.0/0
Endpoint = [some hash].myfritz.net:[some port]

Solution
The limitation is, that we might not be able to load any configuration file on the router, but using configuration files for creating Wireguard VPNs seems to be possible for this router in general.
We probably need to add some port mapping/forwarding: between the data logger and the VPN to the PC (Wireguard 2) or between the two VPNs (if we need them at all)?

Where do you see the same interface address, if you also said that the Address= is specifically different between the two configurations? Can you include the configuration from the router – specifically, what AllowedIPs does it use for each peer, and does its local network also use the same 192.168.115.0/24 network?

@grawity_u1686 true: I've tried to clarify this: same address for the Wireguard configuration of e.g. router and data logger. The two VPNs of the logger do have different addresses.
